# Typescript if and if not with boolean and string

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am editing an app using TypeScript React and Meteor. Currently I got the following state:

```
  {user && ( ... )}
```

This shows some data only if the visitor is a logged in user. I although want to show the data **only** if the tournament is **not** cancelled. So I tried to add

```
  {user && !tournament.state === 'cancelled' && ( ... )}
```

which does not work. I receive the following linter message:

> Operator '===' cannot be applied to types 'boolean' and '"cancelled"'.

How can I solve this puzzle?

Comment: ...there has to be a dupetarget for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript complains because you are trying to compare a boolean value: `!tournament.state` to a string: `'cancelled'`.

The `!` symbol is going to turn a **truthy**/**falsy** result into an **boolean**. This happens because assuming `tournament.state` is equal to `'cancelled'`:

```
!tournament.state = !'cancelled' = false
```

The triple equals operator then checks both *value* and *type*. Your code will not only be disliked by TypeScript, it is also incorrect, as every value of `tournament.state` is going to fail the check, because it will always end up as a boolean against a string. What you need is:

```
{user && tournament.state !== 'cancelled' && ( ... )}
```

Answer (score 5):

`!tournament.state` negates `tournament.state`, not the `===` that follows, resulting in `true` or `false` for that part, giving you `true === 'cancelled'` or `false === 'cancelled'. Hence the issue with using`===` on a boolean and a string.

Use `!==`:

```
{user && tournament.state !== 'cancelled' &&
```

Technically, you can use parentheses as well, but it wouldn't be idiomatic:

```
{user && !(tournament.state === 'cancelled') &&
```